# Calculate correct percentage for each day

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `tbl_answer`. It save record for each user when they answer question for each day.

Here is the sample of the table.

```
id    date                      correct    user_id   question_id
1     2015-11-17 06:13:17       yes        11        1
2     2015-11-17 06:24:54       no         1         19
3     2015-11-18 02:09:13       no         129       88
4     2015-11-18 03:16:18       yes        12        98
5     2015-11-20 04:21:24       no         117       4
5     2015-11-20 04:29:24       yes        15        9
....
....
etc
```

There are a lot of records. In same day, many users are answers a lot of questions. So, some day record are repeat with another different value.

Now, I want to calculate total percent of correct answer for each day. And I don't want to show `H:m:i`.

So, I try with this query,

```
SELECT DATE(date) as date,
        ( ( select COUNT(case when correct='yes' then 1 END) )*100 / (count(DATE(date))) ) as percent 
FROM tbl_answer 
GROUP BY date
```

After that, I got this result.

[image: result]

So, I need to sum those different percent for the same day.

For example,
if there are 113 question was answer in 2015-11-24 and
correct question is only 72. So, the correct percent of answer in 2015-11-24  is 63.71%.

So, I try query like this,

```
SELECT temp.date, SUM(temp.percent) AS total_percent 
FROM (  SELECT DATE(date) as date,
        ( ( select COUNT(case when correct='yes' then 1 END) )*100 / ( count(DATE(date))) ) as percent 
        FROM tbl_answer 
        GROUP BY date
    ) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.date
```

But, I get wrong result like this,

[image: result]

I think `(count(DATE(date)))` is not working. I try to count how many questions in each day with `(count(DATE(date)))` but I'm not sure why its not work.

But now, it show only `7200.0`. I already divide `7200/(count(DATE(date)))`. But I don't know why its not working.

Comment: why is the outer most select query needed?

Comment: I have same different percent with same date. So, I use outer most query to sum the percent of the same day

Comment: How can you get different percentage having same date? As I can see you grouped by date so no duplicate records will be found for same date.

Comment: would you please try this query? `SELECT 
DATE(date) as date,
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN correct='yes' then 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0,2) correctPercentage        
FROM tbl_answer 
GROUP BY date`

Comment: When I try as you said, I get the percent as first image. I need to sum those different percent for same day. And I merge your query and my outer most query the result is same like second image. Please help me.

Comment: please post your `create table` code with some `INSERT` statements

Comment: Now, I add more explanation about the table. I think its enough for the problem. I very appreciate for your help. Can you check my question again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are some unnecessary `group by` in your query. I don't think that will result in correct output. So I adopt the following query.**

Since you want date wise percentage of correct answer so the following query might suit your need.

Here's I've created the following table in order to test the query:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_answer` (
`ID`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`date`  timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`correct`  char(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m-%d") `date`,
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN correct = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) * 100.0, 2) correctPercentage       
FROM tbl_answer 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

**Some sample data:**

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('1', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('2', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('3', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('4', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('5', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('6', '2016-02-02 00:00:00', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('7', '2016-02-02 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('8', '2016-02-02 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('9', '2016-02-02 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('10', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('11', '2016-02-08 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('12', '2016-02-07 00:00:00', 'no');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('13', '2016-02-07 00:00:00', 'yes');
INSERT INTO `tbl_answer` VALUES ('14', '2016-02-07 00:00:00', 'no');
```

How the table `tbl_answer` looks like with these data:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Output Explained:**

- There are total 7 entries of **2016-02-08** date out of 3 are correct. **(3/7 = 42.86)**
- There are total 4 entries of **2016-02-02** date out of 1 is correct. **(1/4 = 25.00)**
- There are total 3 entries of **2016-02-07** date out of 1 is correct. **(1/3 = 33.33)**

Comment: Now, I add a little more explanation in my question. In my table, I use `timestamp` for date. Please help me.

Comment: Now, I add a little more explanation in my question. In my table, I use `timestamp` for date. When I try as you said, I got result like your first input sample data. I think its because of the `timestamp` for date in my table. Please help me.

Comment: I've modified my query based on `timestamp` data type. Please check now @NightMare

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, I got it. :)